# How to access child scope in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="some repeat clause">
    <my-div></my-div>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
.directive('myDiv', function({
   return {
       controller: function($scope) {
           $scope.$on('someEvent', function() {
               console.log('siyou here');
           });
       }
   }
}))
```

Controller:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('someEvent'); // cannot trigger 'someEvent' in directive
```

Question:
How can I trigger the "someEvent" in directive from controller?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of `$broadcast` events for such cases. You could use `ng-ref` directive to pass a property into directive and trigger a directive's function any time you want:

```
<my-div ng-ref="refs[index]"> </my-div>
```

Check the example from the official documentation also:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRef